# Automated patching of packages on upstream updates

Tags: package-management, software-updates, patch

Is there a way to automatically merge custom patches to upstream packages when they update? From what I gathered so far modifying source code requires you to maintain a separate fork of packages that you need to maintain.

I'm hoping that instead some package manager or another tool can automatically patch small changes (different keybindings, icons etc.) on each update.

Is it something that shouldn't be done? Is it designed this way intentionally to prevent users from "hogging" their custom changes and instead contribute upstream?

Comment: Ubuntu PPA, Fedora CORP, Suse Open Build Service are meant to deal with this.

Comment: Fedora [COPR](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/) (not CORP), although I'm not sure any of those services are meant to deal with this specific question: they're just build services; you can also build packages locally with just as much flexibility. There's no design that prevents you from automating the patch and build process locally, although at some point your patches won't apply cleanly and you'll need to perform manual maintenance.

Comment: @larsks thanks, are you aware of any example of such automated patching of the build process? Manual maintenance isn't an issue if there was a tool that informs you when it's needed instead of failing silently.

Comment: What @larsks wrote, their last sentence implying that just no one on earth would want that process to be *"automated"*

Comment: Adding that it would also highly depend on the package. Who would want that for whatever related to the toolchain, + qt, gtk…

Comment: E.g. Github's Dependabot tries to generate security patches which can be automatically applied. It's not always possible, and the automation is usually set up to generate a PR and require manual approval. There is nothing stopping you from automating this, but given the failure scenarios, it is unlikely to work very well in practice. A successful system would essentially require the upstream maintainer to be mindful of this process and take care to always make updates fully automatable.

Comment: @MC68020 wouldn't it be useful though when making small patches (e.g. changing keybindings like in suckless tools)?

Comment: @tripleee thanks for that example, I'll check it out. I think that some manual intervention wouldn't be a problem in case of very small patches (e.g. changing keybindings in the source code like in suckless tools).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObXkcd: https://xkcd.com/1319/

Like anything, this can be automated, with some constraints; specifically, your changes may no longer apply to an updated upstream.

If you’re tracking an upstream project (rather than packages), you could make your changes on a branch, and periodically rebase the branch. For example, a cron job could do

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git fetch upstream
git rebase upstream/main
```

to rebase the current branch in a given repository on the main branch in the upstream repository (assuming the remote is named “upstream”); if this succeeds, your repository will be updated with your changes applied, and if it doesn’t, you’ll get an email and you’ll have to sort things out manually.

You can automatically abort the rebase if you prefer:

```
git rebase upstream/main || git rebase --abort
```

Note that even if this appears to succeed, the result may not work; it’s entirely possible for upstream changes to render a downstream patch invalid, while still allowing the patch to be applied.

If you’re tracking packages, there might be tools available to help you. For example, Debian derivatives have [`apt-src`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/apt-src), which can be used to install packages from source. It supports an `upgrade` operation which will upgrade locally-installed source packages, while attempting to preserve local changes.

Comment: thanks a lot, I previously assumed that "apt upgrade" will just overwrite any previous changes. If it doesn't, I think that it would be the simplest way to do it. I've never heard anyone try this before though or haven't found any examples. I will take a look at apt-src process and how easy it will be to start applying patches through it.

Comment: Yes, `apt upgrade` will overwrite any local changes; `apt-src upgrade` is different, make sure you use the latter for patched packages.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks again :)